# SQL Server ODBC / T-SQL - Pass back a CURSOR type to an ODBC caller?

Tags: c, t-sql, stored-procedures, odbc

I have the following pattern set of T-SQL stored procedures:

- First - open a cursor and pass it back to the caller.
- Next  - Step along that cursor iteratively and fetch the data.
- Finally - close the cursor and deallocate it

works fine in T-SQL - as shown below. - I do not manage to make it work for an ODBC caller.

following code fragment fails regardless of the type passed to `SQLBindParameter(...)` showing the error  below:

```
res = SQLPrepareW(stmt,(SQLWCHAR *)L"exec CDClog5.dbo.openNationCursor ?", cb);
SQLNumParams(stmt, &NumParams);
res = SQLDescribeParam(stmt,1,&DataType,&bytesRemaining,&DecimalDigits,&Nullable);

res = SQLBindParameter(stmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, DataType,DataType, 10, 0, &iCursor, 4, &cbParm1);
res = SQLExecDirectW(stmt, (SQLWCHAR *)__EXEC_SP_OPEN__, SQL_NTS);

if( !SQL_OK( res ))
{
    printErrors( SQL_NULL_HENV, SQL_NULL_HDBC, stmt );
    exit( -3 );
}
```

Error:

> SQLState     = 22005
>   Native error = 206
>   Message text = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with cursor**

**Note**: due to various considerations - the stored procedure pattern is a constraint which cannot be changed or bypassed.

Please do not answer with "Hey - change it into an ordinary programmed ODBC cursor". I wish I could...

What did I miss here?

How can I pass a CURSOR type from/to T-SQL?

Your assistance is most welcome.

Thanks.

Hillel.

```
/*
    Creation script
    ===============
*/
if object_id('dbo.openNationCursor') is not null
    drop   procedure  dbo.openNationCursor
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.openNationCursor
    @nationCursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS
    SET @nationCursor = CURSOR
    FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
      SELECT n_nationkey,n_name
      FROM dbo.nation order by 1
    OPEN @nationCursor;
-- ===========================

if object_id('dbo.closeNationCursor') is not null
    drop PROCEDURE dbo.closeNationCursor
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.closeNationCursor
    @nationCursor CURSOR VARYING output
AS
    close @nationCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @nationCursor; 
GO
-- ===========================

if object_id('dbo.fetchNationCursor') is not null
    drop PROCEDURE dbo.fetchNationCursor
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.fetchNationCursor
    @nationCursor CURSOR VARYING output,
    @n_nationkey  integer output,
    @n_name       varchar(64) output
AS
    FETCH NEXT FROM @nationCursor INTO @n_nationkey,@n_name 
GO

-- ===========================
-- Execute from TSQL
-- ===========================

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR; 
declare @n_nationkey integer
declare @n_name varchar(64)

EXEC dbo.openNationCursor @nationCursor  = @MyCursor OUTPUT;  

EXEC dbo.fetchNationCursor @nationCursor  = @MyCursor, @n_nationkey  = @n_nationkey output, @n_name = @n_name output

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)  
BEGIN 
     print cast(@n_nationkey as varchar(10))+' '+@n_name
    EXEC dbo.fetchNationCursor @nationCursor  = @MyCursor, @n_nationkey  = @n_nationkey output, @n_name = @n_name output
END 
EXEC dbo.closeNationCursor @nationCursor  = @MyCursor;   
GO
```

0 ALGERIA
1 ARGENTINA
2 BRAZIL
3 CANADA
4 EGYPT
5 ETHIOPIA
6 FRANCE
7 GERMANY

So - the procedures work fine when called from TSQL but fail on the very basic initialization step when called from ODBC
Any clue?

Comment: What language are you using for odbc? Is it a C++ variant?

Comment: This modeling piece is coded in plain "C".

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 on Windows 10 platform. For the sake compatibility across platforms - the project in which I am involved use plain "C" as a preferred choice.

Comment: You should tag your question with that information. It will be easier to find someone that can answer you.